# Windows MBR Overritten by linux command dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count1

Tags: linux, windows, partition, mbr

I know it's a stupid thing what I have done : In a Linux Virtual machine I did dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count1 to my external hard disk containing windows

Now I Cannot detect the external Hard drive in my windows machine.
I thing the MBR Partition is gone

What to do now ? any way to resotre my data on the external Hard disk ?

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to fix this from Linux, using the [boot-repair](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/) tool:

More information is on the link given, and is too long to include all here.

Comment: Thanks, does this work even if my external HDD is windows ? This will be detectable in a windows machie ?